# Vector2 cast to Vector3 in C#/Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had some code like this

```
Vector3 someFun (Vector2 v) {

    return new Vector2 (...);
}
```

As you see the types dont match but there is no error. Does `Vector2` inherit from `Vector3` or is there a cast between the two?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding their documentation as found [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html), they use implicit operators to convert a Vector3 to a Vector2 and vice versa. I think that they are structs (for greater performance), which rules out inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the needed values in the `Vector3` constructor:

```
Vector3 someFun (Vector2 v) {

    return new Vector3 (v.x, v.y, 0.0f);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked, which is not "how can I return a Vector2 as a Vector3?" but "why is there no error when I return a Vector2 when expecting a Vector3?"

Comment: While it may not be the perfect answer for this question, I still find this answer very helpful. Instead of down voting an answer due to your beliefs, you should flag the answer and allow the administrators to make the distinction where they will then either remove the answer or not.

As the answer has not been removed by an administrator after 8 years, it must be considered a valid answer for now.